# Intercept hyperlink clicks

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to intercept clicks on this link:

```
<a id="test-button" href="#">Test</a>
```

with this js:

```
(function() {
    $('#test-button').click(function (event) {
        console.log("This code never gets called.")
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#alert-placeholder').html(['<div class="alert"><a class="close"',
                                      'data-dismiss="alert">×</a>',
                                      '<span>"+message+"</span></div>'].join())
        return false;
    })
    console.log("yes, this code loads");
    debugger;
})();
```

but the URL `'#'` loads and the code in the click() function doesn't run. What am I missing?

I'm using this code in a flask app using bootstrap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to attach an event handler to the element that doesn't exist yet

```
(function() {
})();
```

only creates a local scope but doesn't guarantee DOM to load. To confirm it - add `console.log($('#test-button').length);` to your code.

What you need is to wrap your code with

```
$(function() {
    // your code is here
});
```

instead